# Know when media scanner is done working

Tags: java, android, android-mediascanner

How can I know when Android's MediaScanner has indexed everything?  I would like to wait to show something dependent on the image and video content providers until the media scanner has done it's thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED

See:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/45dbc0ef2e0ca9f1?pli=1

Comment: Answers my question and the link points out a pitfall. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The MediaScanner service does this: `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED, uri));` when the scan is finished. Catch that Intent and you should be good.